# Why the MVC querystring's are missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a weird problem with querystrings in MVC actions. Here is what I have:

First I have an action with multiple parameters:

```
public ActionResult Index(string p1, string p2, string action, string controller, string p5)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p1) 
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p2) 
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(action) 
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(controller) 
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p5))
    {
         return View();
    }

    else
    {
        TempData["error"] = "Values missing";
        return View();
    }
}
```

The URL of the page is like this:
`Home/Index?p1=1&p2=2&action=3&controller=4&p5=5`

Then in the view I'm sending a POST with a simple beginform

```
using(Html.BeginForm("GetValues", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.p1, new{ Value = Request.QueryString["p1"] })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.p2, new{ Value = Request.QueryString["p2"] })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.action, new{ Value = Request.QueryString["action"] })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.controller, new{ Value = Request.QueryString["controller"] })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.p5, new{ Value = Request.QueryString["p5"] })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OtherField)

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
<script>
    $(function(){
       $.ajax({
       url: "/Home/OtherAction",
       type: "GET",
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
            $("#OtherField").val(result.OtherField);
      }
      });
    });
</script>
```

After I POST the values, I receive them in my other action like this one:

```
public ActionResult GetValues(ViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         //I execute my code
    }
    else
    {
         //I have the p1,p2,action,controller,p5 correctly and OtherField is null, so I return to the Index action with the parameters I HAVE CORRECTLY
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new{ p1 = model.p1, p2 = model.p2, action = model.action, controller = model.controller, p5 = model.p5})
    }
}
```

So technically I am redirecting to `Index` again with the same parameters, event the view is returning correctly but when the page finish loading. **I am missing the paramers `action and controller` even though I'm validating if is null or empty and I have no problem with that (because the values in the action parameters are fine). The problem is that in the browser I'm missing the querystrings.**

Final result: 
`Home/Index?p1=1&p2=2,p5=5`

Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks to @Stephen Muecke I edit my question so other know which was the exact problem. The reserved words are `action` and `controller`, even though is a string parameter, the url containing parameter and controller are reserved words for the routing of the website so automatically its omitted.

Comment: Please post the view

Comment: Also, post the url the browser is showing after the redirect.

Comment: It would help greatly if you used your debugger / browser developer tools to determine the exact spot in this chain of multiple server requests that the params became missing. Otherwise, any responses we would give are merely guesses.

Comment: I use the debbuger in the visual studio and when I put the breakpoints between those 2 actions, the parameter is still valid and return the correct View

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? The code you've posted works fine in MVC5

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question because I could figure it out what was the problem. `Action` and `controller` are reserved words,  not highlighted by visual studio. So when I tried to read from the querystring it was parsing or reading the reserved word and hiding the parameter.

Comment: That information is not in your question, so either edit the question to include it or delete the question - its of no use to anyone else and the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, when I wrote the question I didn't know action and controller were reserved words so I didn't include them in the question, know it's on the question.